# Is space time interval formula $ds^2=\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ changed in presence of gravitational wave perturbation?

Tags: gravitational-waves

In relativity theory, in absence of any perturbation of the space time, we have conservation of spacetime interval : 
$$ds^2=\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$$

where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric.

In presence of a gravitation wave, there is distorsion of the metric.
Let's call $h_{\mu\nu}$ the deformation.

We have :
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$$

My question is thus : in presence of a deformation of the metric by a gravitational wave, is the space time interval formula changed ?

Said in a different way, 
should we write :

$$ds^2=\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$$
(there is no impact of the gravitational wave on the interval space time that is defined without perturbation), or

$$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=(\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu})dx^\mu dx^\nu \quad\text{?}$$

Comment: If gravitational waves didn’t affect the spacetime interval, LIGO wouldn’t detect them.

Comment: Apologizes for the final equality. I have fixed it. Ok, so you mean that the correct formula is the last one. So, why in cosmology books and or web sites, they sometimes write the first formula ? Is it because they didn't anticipated the possibility of gravitational wave ? I mean : the second formula, with $g_{\mu\nu}$ would always work.

Comment: Of course gravitational waves change the metric. That's basically the definition of what a gravitational wave is!

Comment: *So, why in cosmology books and or web sites, they sometimes write the first formula?* Can you mention a cosmology book that does this (use the Minkowski metric for cosmology!), and the page number? As for websites, you can find all sorts of misleading garbage on websites.

Comment: @G. Smith : no : I have not a concrete example : I *thought* to have seen that in the past, but I could no more find. Ok, I think that the problem is solved, thanks to you and knzhou. Thank for you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kip Thorne's lecture notes he derives the effect of a gravitational wave in two different coordinate systems (both of which I use $dx^{\mu}$ for in what follows). The first he calls "Local Lorentz Coordinates" in which the gravitational wave does not change $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ but does change $dx^{\mu}$. The second he calls "Transverse Traceless Gauge" in which the gravitational wave changes $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ but does not change $dx^{\mu}$.  He shows the space time interval $ds^2$ changes the same way for both sets of coordinates.

From one way of thinking, this is a peculiar result.  We think of $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$ being a tensor relation that makes $ds^2$ invariant to all the linear coordinate transformations rotations, boosts (which are space-time strains), and space-space strains (which seem to be gravitational waves).  All these transformations form the group SL(4). When we ask what the metric and coordinate values are for an event seen in a transformed (rotated, boosted) frame compared to the Lab frame, we have to transform both the metric and the coordinates, and $ds^2$ remains invariant.  Actually, we never thought much about whether we should rotate/boost the metric because our flat space metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ remains the same whether rotated/boosted or not.  But the flat space $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is not invariant under space-space strains.  If gravity waves are a space-space strain that does frame transformations like its compatriots rotations/boosts in SL(4), then $ds^2$ should be invariant and both metric and coordinates should be strained...and a Michelson Interferometer would not be able to detect gravitational waves.  Since LIGO reports seeing gravitational waves, a gravitational wave must not be doing an SL(4) frame transformation that strains everything, but peculiarly picks out just the metric or just the coordinates to strain and therefore changes $ds^2$.